# How copy current line to the clipboard?

Tags: text-editing, clipboard

This [Emacs Wiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyingWholeLines#:%7E:text=Standard%20Emacs,-There%20are%20various&text=You%20can%20also%20use%20either,Meta%20key%20while%20you%20click.&text=%27C%2Da%20C%2DSPC%20C%2De%20M%2Dw,current%20line%20without%20the%20newline.)

says:

```
‘C-a C-SPC C-e M-w’ copies the current line without the newline.
```

But it doesn't work to me. I'm using Emacs 26. Is there some other shortcut?

P.S.
I use CUA keys in my Emacs

Comment: What does "not work" mean? The sequence of shortcuts means selecting the current line then copy, so it should work, you can test it from Emacs -Q.

Comment: @xuchunyang How I use more shorter shortcut for this?

Comment: You can use `C-a C-S-e M-w` if know you know [(emacs) Shift Selection](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shift-Selection.html), however, you can also write a new command to do whatever you want and assign a shortcut to it, e.g., write `your-copy-region-or-current-line` and assign `M-w`.

Comment: @xuchunyang I'm can't use C-a because this select whole content of buffer

Comment: By default, C-a runs `move-beginning-of-line`, which moves point to the beginning of the line.

Comment: If you really want a shorter shortcut, you may consider using `evil-mode`. Then, copy the current line would be simply `y y`, `V y`, or even `Y` in normal mode. However, knowing the keybinding you mentioned is still useful when you want to copy snippet in minibuffer.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify it, rather than adding info via comments (those won't always be visible).

Comment: An alternate option is to use the package `expand-line` and bind a key to highlight the whole line. Then you can use regular copy/paste keybindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

```
(defun my-line-save ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((l(substring (thing-at-point 'line)0 -1)))
    (kill-new l)
    (message "saved : %s" l)))
```

can do the trick, just assign the keys of your choice

```
(local-set-key (kbd "C-c w") #'my-line-save)
```

or whatever keys you like.

Answer (score 3):

`C-a C-SPC C-e M-w` does work in all versions of Emacs. The only reason it doesn't work for you is that you've changed the key bindings. If you're using a GUI Emacs, you can use `home S-end C-insert` or `Home S-End M-w` instead. This may or may not work in a terminal, depending on how the terminal passes function keys to Emacs.

> I'm can't use C-a because this select whole content of buffer

This indicates that you're using some third-party package that emulates common line editing packages, badly. Selecting the whole buffer is an extremely uncommon action. It is bad interface design to bind it to an easily-accessible key. I recommend that you stop using this package.

If you want Windows-like key bindings like `C-c/C-x/C-v` for copy/cut/paste, Emacs provides [CUA mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode). I don't recommend using this package because it deviates from standard Emacs key bindings (in particular, `C-c` and `C-x` have very fundamental roles in Emacs), but at least it's a decent interface design, just different from Emacs.

Comment: I use CUA keys in my Emacs

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Shift Key Tip from the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html)

> To enter an Emacs command like <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> while the mark is active, use one of the following methods: either **hold Shift together with the prefix key**, e.g., <kbd>S-C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd>, or quickly type the prefix key twice, e.g., <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd>.

For your specific example:

- **Original Key Chords** <kbd>C-a</kbd> <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd> <kbd>M-w</kbd>
- **Updated Key Chords** <kbd>S-C-a</kbd> <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd> <kbd>M-w</kbd>

Comment: It's to long keybinding